# Java/Postgresql get next X days

Tags: java, postgresql, date

```
public Date getCurrentDay() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf( 
            cal.get(cal.YEAR) + ":" + 
            cal.get(cal.MONTH) + ":" + 
            cal.get(cal.DATE) );
    return date;
}
```

I need to make a database query where CLIENT says he wants info of next 3 days, here is my method for getting the current day, so I can get todays info, but when my client wants next 3 days, how can I make the query. How do I get the next X days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client is in Java, you can just make a helper method to get the days ahead of the current time.:

```
public Date getDaysAheadCurrentDate(int numberOfDaysAhead) {
    if (numberOfDaysAhead <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of days ahead must be a positive integer.");
    }
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add the number of days before creating the java.sql.Date instance.
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, numberOfDaysAhead);
    Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf( 
            cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ":" + 
            cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ":" + 
            cal.get(Calendar.DATE) );
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Note that `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1)` is also valid to get yesterday's date. So the first check is just needed to adhere to the implied semantics of "getDaysAheadCurrentDate" (ahead implies only going forward ;) ).

Comment: Correct Thomas... As the requirement described by the question's author is "days ahead current time", the method verifies if the parameter numberOfDaysAhead is a positive number :)

Answer (score 3):

You can call `cal.add(cal.DATE, 3);` to get the same time 3 days later.

You could do a method like the following:

```
public Date getDaysFromNow(int days) {
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
   Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf( 
        cal.get(cal.YEAR) + ":" + 
        cal.get(cal.MONTH) + ":" + 
        cal.get(cal.DATE) );
   return date;
}

public Date getCurrentDay() {
  return getDaysFromNow(0);
}
```

Edit:

Note that you can also set the time to 0 and then call getTimeInMillis(), i.e.

```
public Date getDaysFromNow(int days, boolean endOfDay) {
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, endOfDay ? 23 : 0);
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,  endOfDay ? 59 : 0);
   cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,  endOfDay ? 59 : 0);
   cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,  endOfDay ? 999 : 0);

   cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
   Date date = new java.sql.Date( cal.getTimeInMillis() );
   return date;
}
```

The endOfDay parameter is used to set the time to 23:59:59,999, thus you could get two dates for today: `2011-29-04 00:00:00,000` and  `2011-29-04 23:59:59,999` with the same method.

Answer (score 2):

In postgres you can use now() to get the current time. You can then use a string expression to get + 3 days.

You can play with these expressions in a postgres client.

```
SELECT now() + '3 days'
```